# Best ways to draw attention on the 'winner' and 'loser' within a table

Tags: website-design, design-patterns

We are building a small tool to compare mortgage terms and their impact on the user's finances in the long term.

This is our attempt with the table. Our goal is to draw some attention on the 15 year and 30 year results while also showing which term is the better one (green being the 'winner' and grey the 'loser'). How would you best draw attention on the winner's and loser's results within a table so that the data in it is easier to digest?

[image]

[Here's](https://www.figma.com/file/UIVES5tCWOoZgfeR8B2jox/2019-08-01-Mortgage?node-id=248%3A0) the full design for context.

Answer (score 2):

I like what you did by highlighting the prices at the 15-year mark, it's an important part of the graph that should be highlighted! I'd highlight the header row for the winner, as well.

I'd also suggest highlighting/enlarging the various points that make the 30year loan a winner. I like the copy you've written in the full design -- you can totally incorporate some of those into the graphs visualization.

This layout is tough for comparison, because the user is scanning back and forth across 9 very-similar columns. Some subtle striping could help. Best case would be hovering over one box and having the equivalent box for the other loan period highlight as well.

Test it out, but I'd also suggest building a view where the individual columns can be compared side-by-side (i.e. Mortgage-15y, Mortgage-30y, Investment-15y, Investment 30y, etc). What is the user most concerned about? Total mortgage left, or mortgage payments for each month?